# R - one week gap on parse_date_time(), return the wrong monday since 2018

Tags: r, date, lubridate, leap-year

I using, from package **lubridate**, the function `parse_date_time()` with the argument `orders = 'YAU'` in order to transform a year and week number into a Monday date. For instance, `'2017Monday1'` give `'2017-01-02'`, the first Monday of the year 2017.

But since 2018, there is a gap of one week.

```
parse_date_time('2018Monday1', orders = 'YAU')
#"2018-01-08 UTC"
```

But the first Monday of 2018 is '2018-01-01', there is a gap of one week. All next week have the same gap, for instance:

```
parse_date_time('2020Monday1', orders = 'YAU')
#"2020-01-06 UTC"      # wrong, it should be 2019-12-30

parse_date_time('2020Monday52', orders = 'YAU')
#"2020-12-28 UTC"      # wrong, it should be 2020-12-21

parse_date_time('2020Monday53', orders = 'YAU')
# NA                   # wrong, it should be 2020-12-28, 2020 counts 53 weeks (leap year).
```

Does someone understand what happen here ?
Thank you.

Comment: @RonakShah:  The ISO 8601 standard says that week 1 of 2020 starts on Monday Dec 30 2019.  The USA doesn't use that standard; in the USA, weeks start on Sunday, except Week 1 starts on Jan 1.  So in 2020, there is no Monday in week 1.

Answer (score 1):

From `?parse_date_time`:

```
     'U' Week of the year as decimal number (00-53 or 0-53) using
          Sunday as the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the
          first Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1).  The US
          convention.
```

This is a 0-based operation, not a 1-based. The first week is numbered 0.

```r
lubridate::parse_date_time('2018Monday0', orders = 'YAU')
# [1] "2018-01-01 UTC"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem perfectly consistent:

```r
lubridate::parse_date_time(paste0(1980:2020, "Monday", 0), "YAU")
# Warning:  36 failed to parse.
#  [1] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
#  [6] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
# [11] "1990-01-01 UTC" NA               NA               NA               NA              
# [16] NA               "1996-01-01 UTC" NA               NA               NA              
# [21] NA               "2001-01-01 UTC" NA               NA               NA              
# [26] NA               NA               "2007-01-01 UTC" NA               NA              
# [31] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
# [36] NA               NA               NA               "2018-01-01 UTC" NA              
# [41] NA
```

It appears that this might be a logical glitch with which you'll need manual intervention.

```r
mondays0 <- paste0(2007:2018, "Monday", 0)
mondays1 <- paste0(2007:2018, "Monday", 1)

lubridate::parse_date_time(mondays0, "YAU")
# Warning:  10 failed to parse.
#  [1] "2007-01-01 UTC" NA               NA               NA               NA              
#  [6] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
# [11] NA               "2018-01-01 UTC"
### okay, we cannot rely on mondays0

(dates <- lubridate::parse_date_time(mondays1, "YAU"))
#  [1] "2007-01-08 UTC" "2008-01-07 UTC" "2009-01-05 UTC" "2010-01-04 UTC" "2011-01-03 UTC"
#  [6] "2012-01-02 UTC" "2013-01-07 UTC" "2014-01-06 UTC" "2015-01-05 UTC" "2016-01-04 UTC"
# [11] "2017-01-02 UTC" "2018-01-08 UTC"
(dates <- dates - ifelse(day(dates) > 7, 7*86400, 0))
#  [1] "2007-01-01 UTC" "2008-01-07 UTC" "2009-01-05 UTC" "2010-01-04 UTC" "2011-01-03 UTC"
#  [6] "2012-01-02 UTC" "2013-01-07 UTC" "2014-01-06 UTC" "2015-01-05 UTC" "2016-01-04 UTC"
# [11] "2017-01-02 UTC" "2018-01-01 UTC"
```

(The first and last entries were the problems before, now fixed.)

I don't know if this is a bug, or if there is some corner-case (leap years, etc) where this cannot be relied on.

Comment: Thank you for the notice of 0-based operation. I don't have same results as you, for instance `parse_date_time('1980Monday0')` return `'1980-01-07'`, not `NA`. In fact, it returns the exact same thing than `parse_date_time('1980Monday0')`.
One solution would be to use 1-based for standard years, and 0-based for leap years ...